# Single Page Application Looking Like Spotify Website

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, single-page-application, singlepage

I want to build a website, where all the content is found on one page. It should look like the following site:

https://www.spotify.com

So that some background parts just move slightly while scrolling.

How can I achieve this? Are there tutorials somewhere?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is alot of js plugins for that,

[Check this out](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/open-source-jquery-plugins-for-building-single-page-website-layouts)